# React Route render with condition

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Ok, i'm really not sure what's wrong here. I have this routes here, everything is working fine except the "/home" route, it's exactly the same as the other routes with conditional renders yet everytime i access "/home" it goes to the Redirect portion("/submit-ticket"). The path "/maintenance/departments" is exactly the same but works fine.

```
    <Route path="/submit-ticket" render = {() => <Ticket/>} />
    <Route
      path="/home"
      render = {() =>
        isAdmin ? (
          <Dashboard />
        ) : (
          <Redirect
            to = {{
              pathname: "/submit-ticket"
            }}
          />
        )
      }
    />
    <Route
      path="/maintenance/departments"
      render = {() =>
        isAdmin ? (
          <DepartmentMaintenance jwtToken={credentials.jwtToken} />
        ) : (
          <Redirect
            to = {{
              pathname: userName ? "/" : "/submit-ticket"
            }}
          />
        )
      }
    />
```

If I render it just like this it works fine, `<Route path="/home" render = {() => <Dashboard/>} />`

I'm new to react so if I need to provide some other code please tell me.

Comment: how do you set `isAdmin`? Can you confirm the state of the variable to be true?

Comment: Also the 2nd case (departments) is slightly different because it also checks for the `userName` before deciding for a redirect path.

Comment: @Stuck yes it's true since the "/maintenance/departments" path works, ```isAdmin``` is true and the DepartmentMaintenance component is rendered.

Also the difference you mentioned is only for the redirect portion, my problem is that even if ```isAdmin``` is true, the "/home" path goes to the Redirect portion instead of rendering the Dashboard component

Comment: do you have other routes defined that might interfere?

Comment: maybe try setting the `/home` route to `exact`, if that works, this hints that another route (`/home/something`) might lead to such behavior.

Comment: @Stuck no, this is the only "/home" path I have and it works fine if i just render the Dashboard component as is without the condition of ```isAdmin```, that's why i'm tearing myself apart wondering why the condition is failing there but not on the other Routes with the same condition.

Comment: From the shown code, that issue should not arise, so there is going on something else in the context. Could you build a minimal example that shows the issue?

Comment: Actually, I put a bet on `<Route path="/home" render = {() => { console.log(isAdmin); return <Dashboard/>; }}` to reveal that `isAdmin` is false. The difference between the routes is at least, that the browser points to a different location and hence your application does something else.